# mysql subtract in select

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, I have the following table:

```
date | id | num
01-01 | a | 10
01-02 | a | 14
01-02 | b | 2
01-03 | a | 19
01-03 | b | 5
01-04 | a | 13
```

I want to substract `num` of `b` from `a`, that is, the result will be:

```
01-01 | 10    //10
01-02 | 12    //14-2
01-03 | 14    //19-5
01-04 | 13    //13
```

I tried the following SQL query but if there is no record of `b` on a `date`, it will return `\N`.

```
SELECT tba.date, numall-numout
FROM (
    SELECT date, num AS numall
    FROM tb
    WHERE id = "a"
) tba
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT date, num AS numout
    FROM tb
    WHERE id = "b"
) tbb
ON tba.date = tbb.date
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there's no matching B, a left join will return a null, meaning you're doing

```
numall - NULL
```

which results in a NULL. To get around this, you'd have to do

```
numall - COALESCE(numout, 0)
```

to force a 0 for the non-existent 'b' dates.

Comment: That's subverting what COALESCE is designed to do, and avoiding using something made for the job: IFNULL. A better solution is `numall - ifnull(numout, 0) because that is more clear what is going on.

Comment: subverting how? coalesce is simply a multi-argument version of ifnull().

Answer (score 0):

Use `SELECT tba.date, numall-ISNULL(numout,0)`